# How to get only return parts of WP_Query result for performance?

Tags: wp-query

I am building a leaderboard for users in my site. Each user will have a custom meta field, `game_won`.  WP_User_Query will be used for sorting users based on the value of this custom meta field.

As there will be about 1000 users in my site, I plan to show the result with pagination for performance issue.

The tricky part is, I want to highlight and show current user's position and those close to his position.  How can I do query and only get some entries(let say 10) with current user being the 4th or 5th entry in the returned entries?